# Will Recca become the 9th flame dragon?

Tags: flame-of-recca

[Resshin](http://flameofrecca.wikia.com/wiki/Resshin), the 8th flame dragon was revealed as Recca's & Kurei's father, [Oka](http://flameofrecca.wikia.com/wiki/%C5%8Cka). Does that mean that *all flame masters* will eventually become a flame dragon after they die? Or does this only apply when a flame master died with regret like stated [here](http://flameofrecca.wikia.com/wiki/%C5%8Cka)?

> When Oka died with regret in his heart, he became the eighth dragon,
>   and took the name of Resshin. Because his flame had an inner shape, he
>   was able to retain his natural power and did not become a useless
>   dragon.

Was there any official explanation about this? I haven't read the manga so I don't know if the answer was explained there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was revealed later that Recca was not a flame master like the others, he had inherited the former flame dragons, but he himself had no unique flame ability. Therefore, when he dies, he might become a flame dragon, but he'd be a useless one.

From Volume 16 - Chapter 153:

[image]

Comment: Revealed later where? Can you provide a reliable source (eg. links, etc.) where your answer came from?

Comment: To answer the original question: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Qk5Uv.jpg